# How do I track the strength of a magnetic field to 1:20,000?

Tags: magnetometer

I need to track the change in field strength of a (nominally) 1 Tesla Samarium-Cobalt magnet as a function of temperature. It is specified to be less than 50ppm/degC.

Is there any simple technology available that will do this? I was thinking along the lines of magnetoresistive materials, but any tech suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the magnet at a fixed RPM or move it precisely in linear motion and use a pickup coil.. A similar principle is used in commercial VSM (vibrating sample magnetometer) instruments.

Of course you can use a DC magnetometer (flux gate or Hall or GMR etc.) but the magnetometer will be temperature sensitive and will respond to the earth's field and whatever ferromagnetic materials around it are doing to the earth's field, which in turn may change with temperature.

Comment: Magnet is fixed in a piece of equipment

Comment: Not so convenient. If the field at the point where you are measuring it is anything like 1T I guess you don't need to worry too much about the earth's field, but dimensional stability and other experimental methods are going to be critical, particularly if you're trying to force a temperature change. The wiki page says those magnets change -500ppm/degree C but gadolinium can be added to the alloy to reduce the magnetic field coefficient. CTE is tens of ppm/degree.

Answer (score 0):

Simple? Not likely.

Converting a magnetic field to a current or voltage is pretty straightforward, as @Spehro Pelhany has answered, but measuring an AC voltage to .005% is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: The OP wants a (relative) change. Rotating slowly, and synchronizing a sample to a mechanical index, gives a DC measurement. Lotta 20-bit ADCs out there. Even 22-bit or 24-bit.

Comment: For low levels you might need a lock-in amplifier but in this case, probably a regular old bench multimeter would do the trick if kept at constant temperature especially. My 34401A is rated for 0.005% for 10 minutes, which is likely conservative. Obviously I would try to change the temperature by more than 1 degree C- if 20 degrees was possible it would be a slam dunk.